# Meteor: set context inside template if context exists

Tags: templates, meteor, routes

I have the problem that I want to render the same form template for a `/edit/:id`-route and a `/add`-route. Latter should provide the form with empty inputs, the first should populate the input fields with existing attributes of an object, let's say it's a Post.

Keeping it DRY I don't want to copy paste the template into a new one.

To achieve this I did the following:

```
<template name="addOrEditPost">
  {{#if this.post}}
    {{#with this.post}}
  {{/if}}
  <form>
    <input type="text" value={{#if name}}{{name}}{{/if}} ...>
    ...
  </form>
  {{#if this.post}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

My idea was, to only give the template a context, if the context itself exists (if it exists, we're in 'edit'. If not, we're in 'add').

But this leads into

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/views/admin/addPost.html:6: Expected tag to close with, found if
...{#with this.post}}   {{/if}}   <form id="...
^
```

So how can I achieve this without duplicating the whole template and form? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have to mention that it is working without `{{with}}`-context: When I write

```
<input type="text" value={{#if this.post.name}}{{this.post.name}}{{/if}} ...>
```

it is working. But still, a context would be much cleaner since the form has about 50 input fields...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a solution by my own:

```
<template name="addOrEditPost">
  {{#if this.post}}
    {{> form this.post}}
  {{else}}
    {{> form}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

If there is a Post, I can call its attributes with `{{whatever}}` inside the `form`-template because `this.post` is passed as an argument to the template and serves as its context.

If you have ideas how to still improve this, please share your thoughts. Thanks.